# jQuery NiceScroll does not appear / enable before dragging the content

Tags: jquery, css, nicescroll

I have a website, which have a DIV containing contents that requires scrolling within, using `overflow: auto`.

```
<div class="product_list">
    <ul class="col">
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
        <li>Product A - Long Long Name</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper .product_list {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.wrapper .product_list ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
}
.wrapper .product_list li {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    margin-right: 55px;
    width: 45%;
}
```

jQuery NiceScroll is installed to `.product_list` as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product_list').niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#FF0000", cursoropacitymax: 0.5, cursorwidth: 7});
});
```

However, the `.product_list` cannot be scrolled until I drag the contents in the `.product_list`. What would cause the problem?

Live site: http://www.on-ce.com.hk/dev/ (click the top menu "Our Products", the `.product_list` will show)

p.s. NiceScroll adds `tabindex="5005" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none;"` to `.product_list`.

Comment: I am not sure but can you try adding this code too:  `$(".product_list").getNiceScroll().onResize();`

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle for the same, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver I tried. i wish i can reproduce the same thing is JSFiddle. However, it clashes with JSFiddle's JS...

Comment: @ImranBughio I tried, `$(".product_list").getNiceScroll().resize()` (yeah, the function should be `resize()`). After calling this, the scrollbar ends up moving to incorrect position.

Comment: hmm, hard to understand what your saying without jsfiddle. got any alternative  ?